# how to write an asynchronous get request for an api

Tags: c#, rest

I received access for an API and I have multiple files I want to send through to the API to be analysed. The responses are saved in json format on my hard drive and I would like them to be saved with different file names.

I would like to send a single file every 3 seconds, so that I don't crash their server. I know how to do it for a single file, but do not know how to automate this for many files.

I have uploaded audiofiles with the names: www.xyz.com/myaudiofile1, www.xyz.com/myaudiofile2,www.xyz.com/myaudiofile3.

I am using Visual Studio and my singular request is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.IO;
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;

namespace TestAudio
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {  try
            {
                var ClientEndpoint = "https://website ";
    var audiofile = "https://myaudiofile1 ";
    var client = new RestClient(ClientEndpoint + audiofile);
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    request.AddHeader("Login", "Login Key");
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\myaudiofile1.json",response.Content);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

}

Comment: The answer would be too broad, but this is basically what you need to do: 1. List all files you need to send (how determines where this files come from)  2. Take all the sending logic to a new method that accepts the required parameters. 3. `foreach` over the files you got and call that method

Comment: If ever you find yourself writing `catch (Exception ex)` then please stop. It is an anti-pattern. You should only ever catch specific exceptions that you can meaningfully handle.

Comment: Can you please let us know what REST library you're using? I'd like a [mcve] and I'd like to know which objects are `IDisposable`.

Comment: I have changed the question to include this.  Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: @Big_D - Any chance you can answer my questions?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) then you can do this:

```
var files = new[] { "myaudiofile1", "myaudiofile2", "myaudiofile3" };

var query =
    Observable
        .Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.0))
        .Zip(files, (_, audiofile) => audiofile)
        .Select(audiofile =>
        {
            var ClientEndpoint = "https://website ";
            var client = new RestClient(ClientEndpoint + audiofile);
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("Login", "Login Key");
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            return (audiofile, response.Content);
        });

var subscription =
    query
        .Subscribe(x => System.IO.File.WriteAllText($@"C:\Users\{x.audiofile}.json", x.Content));
```

It would be useful to know what objects are disposable as that would change the way I would write this code.

Just NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` to get this to work.